# Slick carousel same height slides doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, slick.js

I'm using the **slick carousel** plugin for a project and the slides must have same height no matter what (no fixed height).

According to search results, if I want to all slick carousel item `<div>`s to have the same height, I have to use `flex-box` or `display:table/table-cell` on the child element. But in **slick** none of these layout methods work.

Any ideas what to do in this case?

Comment: Can you please add more details and your current code here?

Comment: Try to reprdouce or post some code to see you issue !

Comment: Or even better, give an live-testable example use the `<>` button